# Use soft hyphen in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I would like to insert a soft hyphen between every letter in a word using C#. for example here is some text:

`Thisisatest => T-h-i-s-i-s-a-t-e-s-t`

'-' is a soft hyphen. How might i do this in C#? I am going to use it in website.

**Note:** I am on .NET 2.0.

Comment: That's PowerShell, although uncannily similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the HTML entity `&shy;` for a soft hyphen:

```
theString = String.Join("&shy;", theString.Select(c => c.ToString()));
```

For .NET 2.0:

```
string[] chars = new string[theString.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < theString.Length; i++) {
  chars[i] = theString[i].ToString();
}
theString = String.Join("&shy;", chars);
```

Or using a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(theString.Length * 6);
foreach (char c in theString) {
  builder.Append(c).Append("&shy;");
}
theString = builder.ToString(0, builder.Length - 5);
```

Comment: I added a version for .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

No LINQ required (but .NET 4.0 needed for the `object[]` overload in `String.Join`):

```
var test = "Thisisatest";
String.Join("&shy;", test.ToCharArray());
```

For poor souls on previous versions:

```
String.Join("&shy;", test.Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

If you happen to use .NET 2.0 (as the OP has now stated), then please see another response as it doesn't need to be typed again.

Comment: Hi Yamen I am getting error "best overloaded method do not match with args' as test.ToCharArray() returns char[] and not string[]

Comment: What .NET framework version are you using? It should match the `String.Join(string, object[])` signature and will perform the necessary `ToString()` on the `char`. I'm having no troubles.

Comment: The overload is available from `4.0`

Comment: @Downvoter without comment that probably didn't read the history of this question (ie no .NET framework was stated, answer updated multiple times). Kept around as it was useful to others. This is not what downvotes are for.

Answer (score 0):

try this

.net 3.5

```
Console.WriteLine( String.Join("&shy;","Thisisatest".ToCharArray().Select(r=>r.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

.net 4.0+

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("&shy;", "Thisisatest".ToCharArray()));
```

Comment: The `.Select(r => r.ToString()).ToArray()` part is redundant.

Comment: No, but it has a generic overload. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx (4.0+)

Comment: i am using .net 4.0 and no extension. it must be in 4.5

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh: I use 4.0, and it's there. Does your project target 4.0?

Comment: ohh sorry i was targeting 3.5. its in .net 4

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple helper method that you can use to add the hyphen between each letter for a given string.

```
    static string Hyphenify(string text)
    {
        return string.Join("-", text.ToArray());
    }
```

You could also add another parameter to enable you to give the separator to use, see below.

```
    static string SpaceLetters(string text, string separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, text.ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:
ASPX page:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOriginalString" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFormattedString" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnFormat" Text="Format" runat="server" OnClick="btnFormat_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

C# Code:

```
protected void btnFormat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string formattedString = "";
    foreach (char c in this.txtOriginalString.Text.ToCharArray())
        formattedString += c + "-";
    this.txtFormattedString.Text = formattedString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
var r = new Regex( @"([A-Za-z0-9])(?!$|\s)" );
var text = "Thisisatest";
var text2=r.Replace( text,"$1-" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```
    string AddHyphens(string s)
    {
        string ret="";
        foreach(char c in s.ToCharArray())
            ret += ret != "" ? "-" + c : c.ToString();
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "sometext";
string output="";
if(str.Length>0)
{
    output=""+str.ElementAt(0);

    for(int i =1; i< str.Length;i++)
        output += "-"+str.ElementAt(i); 
}
```